# import jenkins in python fails on mac

Tags: python, macos, jenkins

I installed the jenkins package on a mac using `sudo easy_install python-jenkins`. The installation went fine, no errors, but when I open python and type in `import jenkins` I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.7-intel/egg/jenkins.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lookup3.so, 6): image not found
```

Googling this did not yield any helpful result.

**Traceback after Editing**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "jenkins.py", line 9, in <module>
    lookup3 = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(get_python_lib(), "lookup3.dynlib"))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lookup3.dynlib, 6): image not found
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
pip uninstall jenkins

pip install python-jenkins
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The module in question isn't compatible with Mac OS X dynamic library conventions.

It tries to load a `lookup3.so` file, but on Mac it'll be `lookup3.dynlib` instead. You can verify this by looking at the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` directory. Then just edit the `jenkins.py` module and replace the `.so` extension with `.dynlib`.

I'd also report this to the [issue tracker of the module](https://github.com/lgastako/jenkins/issues); a simple `if platform.system() == 'Darwin':` switch would keep things loadable across platforms.

Update: Actually, the module stubbornly expects the `lookup3.so` module to be located in the `site-packages` directory instead of with the module itself. It is thus not easy_install compatible. It'll work when you move all the files (unaltered) out of the `.egg` directory straight into your `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` directory.

Comment: in the said directory I can't seem to find `jenkins.py`, there are these two files `jenkins-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg       python_jenkins-0.2-py2.7.egg`

Comment: @cyberbemon: right, the eggs have been installed as zip-files; either re-install them with `easy_install -ZU jenkins` or unzip the `.egg` file by hand, replacing the file with the resulting directory renamed to the same name (so the contents of `jenkins-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg` become a new directory with the exact same name).

Comment: `easy_install -ZU jenkins` this yielded no result, so I tried `gzip  python_jenkins-0.2-py2.7.egg` and now I have a file called ` python_jenkins-0.2-py2.7.egg.gz`, I think I screwed up bad !

Comment: @cyberbemon: :-) Now the `easy_install` command will at least work again as your `.egg` file is now gone; you used gzip to replace the egg with a compressed version. You need to use the `unzip` tool instead. You can `gunzip` the `gz` file if you wish.

Comment: I hate this machine, I tried `easy_install -ZU jenkins` this downloaded a new `.egg` and I tried `sudo unzip` tool and it said `unzip:  cannot find or open jenkins-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg, jenkins-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg.zip or jenkins-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg.ZIP.`

Comment: @cyberbemon: The `-Z` switch already installed it as unzipped; it's a directory now, so you can edit the files inside.

Comment: I added the edit, now it's saying `lookup3.dynlib` not found. I updated the question with full traceback

Comment: @cyberbemon: but is there an actual `lookup3.dynlib` file there? The sourcecode has a `.c` file to be compiled, but I don't know for certain what filename it'll end up in. Check the directory and look for the `lookup3.something` file or similar, that's what the jenkins.py module is trying to load.

Comment: these are the files in the folder `lookup3.py      lookup3.pyc     lookup3.so jenkins.pyc  jenkins.py`

Comment: AhA! Looking over the code again I can see how it completely fails to do the right thing when installed as an egg; it seems to think it must be installed manually instead (so all those files living in `site_packages` instead of in the `.egg`.

Comment: @cyberbemon: Yeah, I think so; sorry to have been shooting from the hip; you get my answers in between other issues. :-P

Comment: I'm cinfused now, do I have to move the files outside of the .egg ?

Comment: @cyberbemon: the package doesn't work *anywhere* installed as an egg; the author wrote it such it will only work installed directly into site-packages, that's where it looks for `lookup3.so` in any case.

Comment: so nothing I can do :\, I have reported the issue. hopefully he/she will fix it !

Answer (score 3):

> OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lookup3.so, 6): image not found

From the directory, 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`,

```
ln -s lookup3.cpython-36m-darwin.so lookup3.so
```

worked for me.

Comment: This is a quick and dirty fix, and it works with me as well on python version 3.7. So the file name is a little different.

Answer (score 2):

I found the lookup.so jenkins.py is trying to load in:

```
/Users/MY-USER/Documents/Telnyx/dev/tdm-get-ips/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lookup3.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

so i changed

```
python3.7/site-packages/jenkins.py
```

Line:

```
lookup3 = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(get_python_lib(), "lookup3.so"))
```

for:

```
lookup3 = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(get_python_lib(), "lookup3.cpython-37m-darwin.so"))
```

And it started working properly.

Comment: Works. But the change will be lost when new version of this file coming.